# Android to PC USB Read/Write

Tags: android, windows, usb

I have a program on PC taking in  string input from USB ( old program) I have a Android (4.X) tablet which needs to provide string input on USB to the program running on PC.
When I used the sample code on Android, following code gives empty hashmap. The PC( tried on 32 bit XP and 64 bit Windows 7) has Android driver.

```
    mManager = (UsbManager)getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    HashMap<String, UsbDevice> devices =  mManager.getDeviceList();
```

Any real working code example talking to PC over USB will help, pl. also point out if any driver etc. needed on Android to talk to PC.

I have tried both the Accessory mode and the host mode( just in case)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure I exactly follow what you're doing here, but if I understand you correctly - it just won't work this way. The `UsbManager.getDeviceList()` is meant to be used with Android devices with USB **host** port, to which some USB **devices** are connected. But, as far as I understand, you connect Android tablet acting as a **device** to your PC acting as a **host** (I guess so, cause you wrote about driver installation).

If you want to communicate between Android USB *device* and some USB *host* (e.g. because your Android device has no USB host capabilities), you need to use accessory mode (I suggest you start with [this Android Developers Blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/05/bright-idea-android-open-accessories.html)). But this mode requires special support on the USB host side (it must talk to the device with [Android Open Accessory Protocol](https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/protocol)). Note, that `getDeviceList()` makes no sense in Accessory mode - first of all, connected accessory is a USB host, not a USB device, and there can be only one USB host on a USB bus.

If you want to communicate with PC using Accessory mode, you may want to try this [AOAP implementation](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/05/bright-idea-android-open-accessories.html) for PC. If all you need is to talk to Android device for some debugging needs, you may want to use [ADB port forwarding](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#forwardports) and TCP connection instead.

Comment: Hi Code Painters , Thanx for the answer , You are right , it is actually the UsbManager.getAccessoryList() call but that returns Null;

Comment: Hi @Code Painters , Thanx for the answer , My Manifest is set up in Accessory mode. Followed the documentation .You are right , it is  the UsbManager.getAccessoryList()  call but that returns Null too .I am working on Android 4.0.3 so I am using the android.hardware.usb.accessory at API level 15. I am debugging on tcp/ip  with a coby kyros with usb debugging mode enabled , but it just does not recognise any accessories (i.e) Windows host Laptop connected to the android coby thru a usb cable. I tried runn'g the app without the debug'r with the usb debug'g mode off , still returning null.

Comment: For the Windows laptop to be recognized as an accessory, you need some implementation of accessory protocol running on it, see the link in my answer.

Comment: @CodePainters Can you let me know how can this be implemented with some code in Android and Server Side or a link to a blog.