# USB Communication between android and PC

Tags: android, usb, serial-communication

Background :I have tried finding help on stackoverflow, android developers, and various other resources on web. This is my last hope.
I am new to communication and starting with implementation of USB. Following are my questions:

1) When I connect my phone to windows PC, which one is host?
Suppose I want to create an application that can send data, am I making my phone host?

2) For the case (Windows PC and Android phone), the other one would be a peripheral or a device? are they same?

3) From android developers website and a windows forum about USB, I understand that there are certain steps that need to be followed, and it's like
- Create an instance of USBManager.
- Create get list of devices
- Choose a device from which you want to establish connection
- Create an interface
- get endpoint from that interface.
- Create instance of DeviceConnections and call bulkTransfer method and send data.

But when I tried above steps, I get device == null.
I don't even know if my understanding for above communication method is correct.

Can someone please help me understand and establish basic communication between a PC and a android phone and send at least "hello world".

Big thank you for even reading such a long question.

Here is code sample of what I have done. here devicelist returns null.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    android.widget.Button usbButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final CustomUSBManager cmanager = new CustomUSBManager();

//1)        //Create instance of USB Manager using getSystemService
        final UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

//2)        //Create a list of devices
        HashMap<String,UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();

        Log.d("Devicelist = ", String.valueOf(deviceList.get(0)));

//3)        //Get a specific device from the list



//-----------------------------------------------------------------

Here is my manifest file.

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.neeraj.usbcommunication1">
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"></uses-feature>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest> 
        final UsbDevice device = deviceList.get(0); //getting first device
```

Comment: _"But when I tried above steps, I get device == null"_ We have no way of knowing what you may have done wrong since you haven't shown us your code.

Comment: Are you familiar with `ADB`, I think you should have a look. Plus your question is too broad for the stack overflow platform.

Comment: I read about ADB, but even before that I need to understand basics which I am not finding in blogs, websites anywhere.
Also, For my usecase, I don't think ADB will be helpful for me.
Can you please suggest me a good article that can answer my questions, I have already given up searching?

Answer (score 4):

This will not work the way you want. The `UsbManager.getDeviceList()` is meant to be used with Android devices with an USB port (for example a tablet). However, you connect an Android device **acting as a device** to your PC **acting as a host**.

If you want to communicate between Android USB device and some USB host you need to use the **accessory mode** (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/). But this mode requires special driver support on the USB host side (which is your PC).

Also note that `getDeviceList()` makes no sense in Accessory mode. This is because the connected accessory is a USB host, not a USB device.

Read more about this in this post: [Android to PC USB Read/Write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095588/android-to-pc-usb-read-write)

Note that my answer is based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14099963/5457878